# App Inventor and Firebase multiple counters/score/likes/rating per maniKey

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, app-inventor

I'm using APP inventor 2 and firebase to store same multiple "like" values for different KEYs. I'm using a like and nolike counters set initially to 0. Firebase stores the values for the different Keys but when I increase the value for the first KEY and call the other KEY, the second KEY takes over this value instead starting from null or the value saved in firebase. I guess I have to zero the like and nolike counters every time after I store a value for a Key so the next KEY doesn't start with the value from the first KEY and I tried but is not working ...  I'm trying to avoid setting counters for every like and notlike button for every mainKEYS as there are a lot of mainKEYS. I'm not sure if this is understandable... all examples I found are for names and text strings, but no for (multiple) counters

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You might want to edit your question and add a screenshot of your **relevant** blocks. You also might want to search for _firebase_ and _lists_ in the [App Inventor](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/firebase$20lists%7Csort:relevance) and [Thunkable](https://community.thunkable.com/search?q=firebase%20lists) forums...